# Why is my query not returning records?

Tags: sql

```
select 
    * 
from 
    @[Sheet1] 
where 
    [Review Button Clicked] = 'no' 
    and [Form Submitted] = 'Submitted'
```

I do have one record in the database that I know for sure has a value for `Review Button Clicked = no` and `Form Submitted = Submitted` but for some reason it is coming back saying there are no records.

Comment: which sql database and would help if you show us your data

Comment: Can you try looking at dump.. something like select dump([Review Button Clicked],16), dump([Form Submitted],16) from @[Sheet1]. This way you would be sure that there aren't any unseen characters in table.

Comment: as a test, could you try `rtrim(ltrim([Review Button Clicked])) = 'no' 
    and rtrim(ltrim([Form Submitted])) = 'Submitted'`? You may have blank spaces